# Migrating from ADODB to PDO

Tags: pdo, prepared-statement, adodb

I have a database query which uses ADODB with unnamed placeholders to insert data into a database and I'm trying to convert it to use PDO but I'm getting an error which is probably due to the syntax I'm using.

What I'm trying:

In an included file I have the following shared function:

```
function insCOA($data) {

    global $dbh;

    try {
        $sth=$dbh->prepare("
        INSERT INTO
            coa
            (
                nom_code,
                acc_title,
                acc_type_id,
                acc_desc
            ) VALUES (
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?
            )
        ");

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
            $sth->execute($data[$i]);
            $last_insert_id = $dbo->lastInsertId();
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Something went wrong. Please report this error.";
        file_put_contents('/PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
    return $last_insert_id;
}
```

In my PHP page I have the following:

```
// Add to coa table
$data = array(
    array(
        $nom_code,              /* nom_code         */
        $acc_title,             /* acc_title        */
        $acc_type_id,           /* acc_type_id      */
        $acc_desc               /* acc_desc         */
    )
);
$coa_id = insCOA($data);
```

The connection is handled elsewhere and is connecting ok. It is exported in a global as $dbh.

The error I'm getting is

Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on a non-object in /common.funcs.php on line 574 (which is where the reference is to lastInsertId() above.

Originally, when using ADODB, the shared function was as follows:

The shared function:

```
function insCOA($data) {

    global $conn;

    $sql    = "
        INSERT INTO
            coa
            (
                nom_code,
                acc_title,
                acc_type_id,
                acc_desc
            ) VALUES (
                ?,
                ?,
                ?,
                ?
            )
    ";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
        if ($conn->Execute($sql,$data[$i]) === false) {
            print 'error' . $conn->ErrorMsg() . '<br />Query: ' . $sql;
        } else {
            $last_insert_id = $conn->Insert_ID();
        }
    }
    return $last_insert_id;
}
```

In the PHP page nothing changed.

Once I've got this working, I'll be able to convert a bunch of other queries, so solving this will be very useful. This is my first attempt to use PDO. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error myself which was:

```
$dbo->lastInsertId();
```

should be

```
$dbh->lastInsertId();
```

It's now working perfectly.